# Drupal 8 get cart item programmatically

Tags: commerce

I need to create pdf of user's cart items with custom header & footer. I decide to create custom module in which I can get cart items details. But I have no idea about how to do this? I have tried:

```
$store_id = 1;
$order_type = 'default';
$cart_manager = \Drupal::service('commerce_cart.cart_manager');
$cart_provider = \Drupal::service('commerce_cart.cart_provider');
$entity_manager = \Drupal::entityManager();
$store = $entity_manager->getStorage('commerce_store')->load($store_id); 
$cart = $cart_provider->getCart($order_type, $store);
foreach ($cart-> getItems() as $order_item) {
    foreach($order_item->getPurchasedEntity() as $purchased_entity){
        print_r($purchased_entity);
    }    
}
```

But it gives an array like

```
Drupal\commerce_product\Entity\ProductVariation Object
(
[values:protected] => Array
    (
        [variation_id] => Array
            (
                [x-default] => 432
            )

        [type] => Array
            (
                [x-default] => product_variations
            )

        [uuid] => Array
            (
                [x-default] => 87d27a77-4bc1-40ff-b3cf-ad3e949ce1b3
            )

        [langcode] => Array
            (
                [x-default] => en
            )

        [status] => Array
            (
                [x-default] => 1
            )

        [uid] => Array
            (
                [x-default] => 9
            )

        [product_id] => Array
            (
                [x-default] => 65
            )

        [sku] => Array
            (
                [x-default] => xx-uua
            )
        [price] => Array
            (
                [x-default] => Array
                    (
                        [number] => 22.000000
                        [currency_code] => USD
                    )

            )
        [field_order_no] => Array
            (
                [x-default] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Array
                            (
                                [value] => PE-5070
                            )

                    )

            )
```

And many more `protected` objects. 
I know I can get `quantity, title & price` easily using drupal function but how can I get few custom details from above array like `field_order_no` in above array, I have some unique attribute assigned to variation that I need to display in pdf?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the top line suggests $purchased_entity is of of type "Drupal\commerce_product\Entity\ProductVariation" which is basically an entity.

All entities have a `->get('field_name')` method.

So for your example to get 'field_order_no' you would do

```
$order_no = $purchased_entity->get('field_order_no')->getValue();
```

You can retrieve the value of any field via the `->getValue()` method which returns an array.

Comment: Thanks! I had spent 6-7 hrs!!

Answer (score 0):

```
$cart_provider = \Drupal::service('commerce_cart.cart_provider');
$cart = $cart_provider->getCart('default');
$order_items = $cart->order_items->referencedEntities();
foreach ($order_items as $order_item) { 
    $product_variation = $order_item->getPurchasedEntity(); 
    $sku = $product_variation->getSku();
    $title = $order_item->title->value;
    $quantity = $order_item->quantity->value;
}
```